# How were the solutions to these differential equations found?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, elliptic-functions

These two very strange differential equations came up yesterday while I was doing a physics problem that I made up:

EQ 1) $y'^{2} = k \sin(y)$

EQ 2) $y'' = k\cos(y)$

where $y'$ means $\frac{dy}{dx}$

With initial conditions:

$y(0) = y'(0) = 0$

[Here is the thread which shows my derivation of these equations and the original problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110869/find-the-exact-angle-as-a-function-of-time-for-a-rod-that-swings-on-a-frictionle)

I then plugged these equations into Wolfram Alpha, and they gave me these results:

[Wolfram: EQ 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28dy%2Fdx%29%5E2+%3D+ksin%28y%29)

[solution1 http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP13591hg9040bceih89ag00005eef63f376f0b02b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=55&w=257.&h=36.](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP13591hg9040bceih89ag00005eef63f376f0b02b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=55&w=257.&h=36.)

[solution2 http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP13621hg9040bceih89ag000056714a816hhac700?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=55&w=257.&h=36.](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP13621hg9040bceih89ag000056714a816hhac700?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=55&w=257.&h=36.)

[Wolfram: EQ 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2y%2Fdx%5E2+%3D+kcos%28y%29+)

[solution1 http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP34961h7f9890752347ad0000552fdd38bccgc0bb?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=34&w=357.&h=40.](http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP34961h7f9890752347ad0000552fdd38bccgc0bb?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=34&w=357.&h=40.)

[solution2 http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP34991h7f9890752347ad000059ead9f1ca0157cb?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=34&w=357.&h=40.](http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP34991h7f9890752347ad000059ead9f1ca0157cb?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=34&w=357.&h=40.)

Where [am is the Jacbi amplitude function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html)

How do you arrive at the two above links as the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ansatz**

This seems to be a case for [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables), as I don't see the variable which you differentiate to on the right hand side of the differential equations:

$$
y'(x) = f(y) \iff 
dy = f(y)\,dx \iff
\int \!\!\frac{dy}{f(y)} = \int\!\! dx = x + C
$$
for some integration constant $C$.

**Equation 1**

This equation features the RHS $f(y) = k \sin y$. Using separation of variables we get

$$
G(y) := \int\limits_{y_0}^y \!\!\frac{dY}{\sqrt{k \sin Y}} = x - x_0
$$

For the initial conditions $(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$ this formula reduces to

$$
G(y) := \int\limits_{0}^y \!\!\frac{dY}{\sqrt{k \sin Y}} = x
$$

This will probably need numerical integration to yield a graph / table $x = G(y)$ and numerical inversion to yield $y = G^{-1}(x)$.

**Connection to the Wolfram Alpha solution**

$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\pi-4\, \mathrm{am}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{k} \, x + C\right) \large | 2\right)\right)
$$
Asking Wolfram Alpha for an indefinite integral using 
[this query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dt+%2F+sqrt%28sin+t%29) yields:

$$
\int \!\!\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\sin t}} = 
- 2\, F\left(\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 t) \,\large|\, 2\right) + C \qquad(*)
$$
for some constant $C$ and $F(z\,|\,m)$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind

$$
F(z \,|\, m) = \int\limits_0^z\!\!\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1 - m \sin^2 t}}
$$

Like $G$ above this $F$ is not an elementary function, but defined by an integral function too.

It is only easier in the sense that this is a well studied function where you can get numerical implementations for, instead of integrating it numerically yourself.

Its inverse is the Jacobi amplitude $\mathrm{am}(w \,|\, m)$ which fulfills
$$
w = F(z \,|\, m) \iff \mathrm{am}(w \,|\, m) = z
$$

**Justification for equation (*)**

$$
F\left(\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 t) \,\large|\, 2\right) = 
\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 t)}\!\!\frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - 2 \sin^2 u}} =
\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 t)}\!\!\frac{du}{\sqrt{\cos 2u}}
$$

because $1 - 2 \sin^2 u = \cos 2u$. With $v = 2u$ this yields

$$
F\left(\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 t) \,\large|\, 2\right) = 
\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2} - t}\!\!\frac{dv}{\sqrt{\cos v}}
$$

with $w = \frac{\pi}{2} - v$ we get

$$
F\left(\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 t) \,\large|\, 2\right) = 
-\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^t\!\!\frac{dw}{\sqrt{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - w)}} =
-\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^t\!\!\frac{dw}{\sqrt{\sin w}}
$$

because $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - w) = \sin w$.

**Equation 2**

For the other equation we need to deal with the second derivative $y''$, the idea here is to treat the first derivative $y'$ formally as another independent variable together with $y$ and have one side of the equation with only $y'$ and the other with only $y$:

$$
y'' = \frac{dy'}{dx} = \frac{dy'}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy'}{dy} y' = k \cos y \iff
y' \, dy' = k \cos y \, dy
$$

Thus

$$
\int\limits_{y'_0}^{y'} \! Y' \, dY' = \int\limits_{y_0}^y \! k \cos Y \, dY \iff
$$

$$
(y')^2 - (y'_0)^2 = \int\limits_{y_0}^y \! 2 k \cos Y \, dY = 2 k \sin y - 2 k \sin y_0
$$

With $(y_0, y'_0) = (0, 0)$ this reduces to

$$
(y')^2 = 2 k \sin y
$$

and yields

$$
G(y) := \int\limits_0^y \!\! \frac{dY}{\sqrt{2 k \sin Y}} = x
$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, but I actually meant to ask how the equations in the Wolfram Alpha links were derived. It seems that there is a way to arrive at a solution for y(x).

Comment: I added some information, which I hope fills the gap.